# How can i connect to mysql using terminal?

Tags: mysql, terminal

I'm trying to connect to the mysql server on my mac using terminal. I've already got MAMP on my mac but now I have installed XAMPP. when I type this into my terminal

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it comes up with this message...

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I'm wondering is it because of XAMPP? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

(if the mysql server isn't running on your local box, substitute the IP address of the mysql server for 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Just tried it, it works ;)..so does that mean everytime i run xampp..do i have to type that into terminal? because i dont need to do that when im using MAMP.

Comment: Not sure, I've never used xampp or mamp I'm just familiar w/ mysql.  If that worked, can you mark the answer as correct.

Comment: You don't need to run that every time you run xampp, just when you want to access the command line client. And you can write an options file to override the defaults so you don't have to type all of that in. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html for details.